# Beyond compare, update the command line

Tags: beyondcompare

After updating beyond compare, in the application folder I have the updated BeyonCompare app. However if I start the application from the terminal with `bcomp file1 file2` the older, not updated version is started.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Beyond Compare** menu's **Install Command Line Tools** command.  It creates a symlink, so that shouldn't be necessary after upgrading, but if your copy of BC was installed somewhere else previously, that will update it.